# Servicestack.Ormlite.Oracle.OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider: Naming strategy for sequences

Tags: oracle, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider sets default sequence names (e.g. for autogenerated id values) to modelName + "_" + fieldName + "_GEN":

Excerpt from OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider.Sequence:

```
var seqName = NamingStrategy.ApplyNameRestrictions(modelName + "_" + fieldName + "_GEN");
```

I am dealing with a legacy system (tables and corresponding sequences already exist) which uses a different pattern: "SEQ_AUTO_".

Is there any easy way to influence the sequence name generation? I am currently using the sequence attribute on each of my DTOs. 
(Unfortunately, the OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider.Sequence methode is private.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sequence Name strategy has now been moved to [INamingStrategy in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/40e0714021b042db42d6be5c88a4980c416709c8).

This now lets you use your own custom Naming Strategy for sequences, e.g:

```
public class MyOracleNamingStrategy : OracleNamingStrategy
{
    public override string GetSequenceName(string table, string field)
    {
        var seqName = ApplyNameRestrictions("SEQ_AUTO_" + table + "_" + field);
        return seqName;
    }
}
```

Which you can register to use in your Oracle Provider with:

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = new OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider { 
    NamingStrategy = new MyOracleNamingStrategy()
};
```

This is available from **v4.0.31+** which is now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: WOW, you're fast...
Thanks a lot!!